# Manually set rounds not working correctly in crypt()

Tags: php, crypt

I had setup a password system which had the system generate a random  digit character and use that as the rounds number for crypting a password.

It worked fine until recently when logins stopped working. After a bit of debugging i realized that the cyrpt() function is not accepting the 4 digits anymore and instead only keeping the first 2 digits.

Example:

Generated Rounds Number:6355
Crypt output: $6$rounds=63$jOa4lXzFPo1W120PzaHk06JjQQ0C/PvmzB6SGdtniZ3hy2OeCQ9WDf2qlFEb9lHikGJcgp7vvI1wZxX4PcJWQ/

As you can see only the first 2 digits are being kept.

Does anyone have a solution to why this suddenly changed?

Comment: Why would you even do that? It’s not more secure in any way.

Comment: But I thought it would be better than a 2 digit number of rounds. How would I go about doing it differently?

Comment: Don’t even bother providing that parameter, it defaults to 5000.

Comment: What about a Salt? - This is what i have now: what should change?    $hashed_password = crypt($validPassword, '$6$rounds='.$rounds.'$'.$salt.'$');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there is no purpose for using a randomized number of rounds. This adds no additional security.

Secondly, it sounds like you are using this to validate passwords of users logging into your site. If that is what you are doing, then using a one way hash rather than encryption is the most secure way.

Comment: Do you mind showing me a one way encryption method worthy of a login system?

Comment: `crypt` with `$6$` *is* a one-way hash.

Comment: @minitech - So my method is ok? also does this look ok? $hashed_password = crypt($validPassword, '$6$');

Comment: @ShadowZzz: Just follow one of the many existing Bcrypt examples. Or use the PHP 5.5 password hashing API. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.password.php

Comment: Please see if this is correct... I couldn't find much resources on SHA-512. $hashed_password = crypt($validPassword, '$6$');